# System with invariant measure, but no ergodic measure.

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

### Question

1. Examples of continuous transformations $T: X \to X$ such that the family of invariant probability measures $M(T)$ is **NOT** empty but there is no ergodic measure ($E(T) = \emptyset$).
   Notice that the measures considered are defined over the Borel sets of $X$.
2. Example of a dynamical system where the following inequality is **strict**:
   $$\sup_{m \in E(T)} h_m(T) < \sup_{\mu \in M(T)} h_\mu(T)$$.

### Background

Consider $T(x) = x + 1$ over the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$.
In this case, $E(T) = M(T) = \emptyset$. The first question asks for a $\emptyset = E(T) \subsetneq M(T)$ example.

In the locally-compact metrizable case, the set of positive invariant measures $\mu$ with $0 \leq \mu(X) \leq 1$ is compact (weak* topology) with extremals with total measures equal to $0$ or $1$. That is, according to [Krein-Milman Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem), if $M(T) \neq \emptyset$, then $E(T) \neq \emptyset$. So, an answer to Question 1 is not supposed to be locally-compact metrizable.

[**Edit:** The question only makes sense if the $\sigma$-algebra is fixed.
So the post was edited, making $X$ a topological space,
$T$ continuous and the $\sigma$-algebra is the family of Borel sets.]

Comment: This post is related to
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76908/supremum-amongst-kolmogorov-sinai-entropies-ergodic-or-just-invariant-measures

Comment: Are you interested in finite measures or infinite measures? What is the notion of entropy you are referring to in the infinite case?
 
Anyways, usually at any question in ergodic theory (especially in entropy theory), one usually deals with "standard" probability spaces (and maybe even Lebesgue spaces).

Comment: @Asaf,  
I am interested on probability measures. The entropy is the Kolmogorov-Sinai entropy.

Comment: What's wrong with using the Krein-Milman theorem in the general situation?

Comment: @Jesse,
The Krein-Milman needs a compact (in some kind of _weak topology_) convex set. For the compact metrizable case, the set of probability measures is compact int the weak* topology. For the locally-compact metrizable case, the set of (positive) measures $\mu$ with $\mu(X) \leq 1$ is weak* compact.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. Metrizability of $X$ doesn't enter in any of your arguments as long as you have local compactness. By its definition the set of positive measures is a weak$^∗$-closed cone in $M(X)$, and thus it cuts out a compact set out of the unit ball, so as soon as you have invariant measures you have invariant ergodic measures by Krein-Milman.

Comment: @Theo: Thank you very much for your comment. You really made me think! Metrizability is for the Riesz Representation Theorem, so we can identify the finite signed measures and the functional linears on $C(X)$. How do you prove the $M(X)$ is weak$^*$ closed? I am more interested in dropping locally-compactness then metrizability.

Comment: @Andre, By general metrization theorems, if your space is separable and metric, it can be embededd into the Hilbert's cube, hence locally compact. 
I think that losing so much topological assumptions might break down the Riesz Rep. theorem. Notice that the proof of Riesz's theorem uses Urysohn's functions, which are basically what you need in order to prove convergence of measurs in the non-compact case (up to some escape of mass).

I must also mention that the Krein-Milman theorem (or Choquet's theorem) works in a very general settings (probably a locally convex topological vector space).

Comment: @Asaf: Subspaces of locally-compact spaces might not be locally-compact. The rationals (or irrationals) are not locally-compact.  
As for the Krein-Milman theorem, what one needs is the topology to be generated by a separating family of linear functionals, and the set in question to be compact in this topology.

Comment: @Andre, thanks for the correction.About the proof of the Banach-Alouglu theorem (and the Riesz theorem),I think you can get them both (at-least for seperable metric cases) from Hilbert's cube.
Embed X inside H,using the Titze extesnion theorem (or Urysohn's theorem),extend every function in C_{c}(X) to C_{c}(H).Given a measure on X, take its push-forward to H. Now using the Banach-Alouglu theorem for C_{c}(H)*,you are getting a weak-* compact set. There you have ergodic measures by Krein-Milman (or ergodic decomposition by Choquet) and you take the pre-images. Notice that mass can escape!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to improve upon my response. I read it again after 4 years and I did not recognise myself.

First, I'd like to point out that asymptotic density is an ergodic and $T$-invariant probability measure on the set of integers $\mathbb Z$ with $T(x) = x+1$.

I'll withdraw the rest of my comment.

Comment: @Daniel: I will correct the post to emphasize that the measure is over the Borel sets and the transformation is continuous. If you are free to choose the $\sigma$-algebra, then you can just take $\{\emptyset, X\}$.

Comment: Am I right in saying that no-one has actually answered either Q1 or Q2 yet? I'm particularly interested in the answer to Q1. (In fact, even ignoring a topology, I haven't managed to find anywhere the answer to the following basic question: Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space that is *not* a Lebesgue space, and let $T:X \to X$ be a $\mu$-preserving measurable map; does there necessarily exist a probability measure $\mu'$ on $(X,\Sigma)$ which is $T$-ergodic?)

Comment: @DanielMansfield: Sorry, I did not see your replies until just now. Thank you for this. Your answer is quite perplexing to me - are you sure it is correct? (And are you perhaps working with a non-standard definition of "conservative"?)

Comment: @JulianNewman: It does not seem to me that Daniel defined his measure over the whole sigma algebra in his first attempt. In his second attempt, there is nothing that ensures the measure $\mu'$ is in fact ergodic.

Comment: @DanielMansfield: Asymptotic density is not $\sigma$-additive: every singleton has density 0, and yet the union of all singletons (i.e. the whole space) has density 1. You are right that asymptotic density is an invariant *finitely additive* measure of the map $n \mapsto n+1$, but it is easy to show that this map has no invariant countably additive probability measures. (Indeed, this is an immediate consequence of the Poincaré recurrence theorem.)